# Do the Gloves of Swimming and Climbing grant you a swimming speed?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, movement, underwater

The rules on [Underwater Combat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#UnderwaterCombat) (PHB pg. 198) state:

> When making a melee weapon attack, a creature that doesn't have a
>   swimming speed (either natural or granted by magic) has disadvantage
>   on the attack roll unless the weapon is a dagger, javelin, shortsword,
>   spear, or trident.

The description of the [Gloves of Swimming and Climbing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/gloves-of-swimming-and-climbing) (DMG pg. 172) says:

> While wearing these gloves, climbing and swimming don't cost you extra
>   movement, and you gain a +5 bonus to Strength (Athletics) checks made
>   to climb or swim.

Would wearing the gloves of swimming and climbing count as having a swimming speed for the purpose of avoiding disadvantage on underwater attack rolls?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## No

There are examples of magic items that do grant as swimming speed, and they state so explicitly.  The [Cloak of the Manta Ray](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/cloak-of-the-manta-ray) (DMG pg. 159), for example, states that "you have a swimming speed of
60 feet."

Since the Gloves do not do so, they do not grant a swimming speed.  They do exactly what they say they do: remove the speed penalty from being underwater, and give you a bonus to certain ability checks.

There are also items that give you a swimming speed *equal to* your walking speed, such as the [Mariner's Armor](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/mariners-armor) (DMG pg. 181.)  This allows you to move at the same speed that the Gloves would, but with all the additional benefits implied by having a true swimming speed.